# PYTHON. Как сделать шансы?

Tags: python

**Например:**
Ты пишешь слово `'Animal'`, и тебе с шансом 50% пишет `Sheep`, с шансом 30% `Cow`, 10% `Сhicken`,
и по 5% `Horse` и `Dog`.

Могу придумать только:

```
from random import randint

num = randint(1,100)

if input() == 'Animal':
    if num >= 50: print('Sheep')
    elif num >= 30: print('Cow')
    elif num >= 10: print('Chiken')
    elif num >= 5: print('Horse')
    else: print('Dog')
```

Но если сделать больше животных например 75
Может есть что-то по короче?

Comment: random.triangular()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
farm = ['Sheep'] * 5 + ['Cow'] * 10
print(random.choice(farm))
```